# Collection: merge keys using lodash

Tags: object, collections, lodash

how to achieve this using lodash?

I have this collection

```
var orginal = [
{ idtsk:1, idevd:1 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:2 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:3 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:4 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:5 },
]
```

and wanna transform into this:

```
var result = [
{ idtsk:1, idevd:[{Id:1},{Id:2},{Id:3}] },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:[{Id:4},{Id:5}] }
]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [
{ idtsk:1, idevd:1 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:2 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:3 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:4 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:5 },
];

var result = _(arr).groupBy('idtsk').map((item, key) => {
    return {
    idtsk: parseInt(key),
    idevd: _(item).map((innerItem) => {
        return {
        id: innerItem.idevd
      }
    }).value()
  }
}).value();

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/farq9dpp/1/

Comment: Hi, tks, but this in inverted. the orginal object is the flat object!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `.groupBy` of array

```
var test = [
{ idtsk:1, idevd:1 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:2 },
{ idtsk:1, idevd:3 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:4 },
{ idtsk:2, idevd:5 },
]

var groups = _.groupBy(test,'idtsk');
var result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key){
     return {
     idtsk:parseInt(key),
     idevd:groups[key].map(function(x){
      return {Id:x.idevd};
     })
    }
   });
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, tks, but this in inverted. the orginal object is the flat object!